# Java utf8 email not working with IE after deploy

Tags: java, email, jsp, character-encoding

i have a mailer class that works fine with IE when i run the application locally, but after deploying it on a server it keeps sending gobbledygook and unreadable characters, i dont see where the problem is, everything is utf8, here is my code :

```
    public static void sendHTMLEmail(String to, String subject, String body)
        throws EmailException {

    HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail();
    email.setSmtpPort(25);
    email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("myMail","myPass"));
    email.setDebug(false);
    email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");


    email.setFrom("webmail@mysite.com","Webmail@mysite");
    email.setCharset("UTF-8");
    email.setSubject(subject);

    // --set Body-- 
    String HTMLBody ="<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>";
    HTMLBody += "<head><meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' /></head>";
    HTMLBody += "<body><div dir='rtl'>";
    HTMLBody += body;
    HTMLBody += "</div></body></html>";
    // -----------

    email.setHtmlMsg(HTMLBody);
    email.setTextMsg("Your email client does not support HTML messages");

    email.addTo(to);
    email.setTLS(true);
    email.send();

}
```

and here are my libraries :

```
import org.apache.commons.mail.DefaultAuthenticator;
import org.apache.commons.mail.Email;
import org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException;
import org.apache.commons.mail.HtmlEmail;
import org.apache.commons.mail.SimpleEmail;
```

thnx for your time

Comment: by the way it works great with all the other browsers

Comment: The actual Java is running on the server; the browser doesn't execute this code. What does come from the browser is the *input* ... I would suggest checking what you're getting from IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume that the `String body` method argument is actually the user-supplied data which has been entered in some `<input>` or `<textarea>` and submitted by a `<form method="post">` in a JSP page.

The data will be submitted using the charset as is been specified in the `Content-Type` header of the page containing the form. If the charset is absent in the `Content-Type` header, then the browser will simply make a best guess and MSIE is generally not that smart as others, it'll just grab the client platform default encoding.

You need to ensure of the following three things to get it all straight:

- Ensure that the HTTP response containing the `<form>` is been sent with `charset=UTF-8` in the `Content-Type` header. You can achieve this by adding the following line to the top of the JSP responsible for generating the response:

  ```
  <%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
  ```

  This not only sets the response encoding to UTF-8, but also implicitly sets the `Content-Type` header to `text/html;charset=UTF-8`.
- Ensure that the servlet which processes the form submit processes the input data in the obtained HTTP request with the same character encoding. You can achieve this by adding the following line *before* you get any information from the request, such as `getParameter()`.

  ```
  request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
  ```

  A more convenient way would be to drop that line in some `Filter` which is been mapped on an URL pattern of interest, so that you don't need to copypaste the line over all servlets.
- Ensure that you **do not** use the `accept-charset` attribute of the `<form>`. MSIE has serious bugs with this.

Comment: MSIE does not properly set charset parameter when posting data, and if using Java serlvets on the server-side, you can get character encoding corruption because the spec says containers should default to ISO-8859-1.  If you are UTF-8 everywhere, you need to configure your servlet container (and/or add a filter) so all data posted is parsed as UTF-8 by the server.

Comment: @ewh: that only applies on GET requests (where the params come in by request URI instead of request body). My answer assumes POST requests. See also http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html#JSPServletRequest

Comment: thnx, let me try that and get back to u

Comment: @BalusC: POST is also affected with IE.  I recently had to deal with this problem where IE will POST urlencoded data in UTF-8 format, but fail to specify the charset in in the Content-Type header, so the servlet engine (i.e. Tomcat) would parse the data as ISO-8859-1 as defined by the spec.  See http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q3

Comment: @dave: you're welcome @ewh: this is to be specified by `HttpServletRequest#setCharacterEncoding()` which I already mentioned in the answer. The filter in the example as mentioned in your wiki link is doing exactly that. The  `URIEncoding` setting is only applicable on GET requests.

Comment: @ewh: No browser passes a Content-Type charset on a POST. Mozilla tried doing it (on the `form-data` subparts) once but it broke many applications that weren't expecting it. So we're stuck with the only input encoding indicator being the originally-IE-only `<input type="hidden" name="_charset">` hack.

Comment: @bobince: Hmmm, there is a difference between an ajax request vs a normal form submittal.  With an Ajax request, Firefox includes `charset=UTF-8` in Content-Type field in the request sent to the server.